# Long names break formatting in the badge list

Tags: bug, formatting

I was scrolling through [the list of awarded Revival badges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) out of curiosity and noticed something a bit strange:

[image: Image showing formatting bug on badge list]

It appears that users with long names cause their user profiles (and the date the badge was awarded at) to be sent to the left of the cell, instead of right-justified, as they should be. I'm assuming this is a bug; I'd guess that the names are overrunning the boundaries of some box and thereby breaking the wrapping. The same thing seems to happen with other users on other badge lists with long usernames

Comment: display:inline-block;

As soon as the element gets too big to be inline it wraps. Looks like the maximum is around 200px as the question has width: calc(100% - 214px);